# set up table view values without using list data types

Tags: javafx, tableview, cell

I have a nested column table in javafx.  Table columns and row created dynamically.  Table values are not consistently filled.  Some cells are empty.

I need to know is there a way to set values cell by cell through a loop or something.

for a example my coloumn data model is below:

```
 TableColumn<RoomRatesTableModel, String> outerColumn1 = new TableColumn<>("Y");
        innerColumn3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RoomRatesTableModel, String>("gender"));
```

I want to add data to table view without using the data model, is it possible???

Comment: no ............

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javafx tableview data from List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171183/javafx-tableview-data-from-list)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008352/inserting-data-to-javafx-tableview-without-intermediate-class) is probably better.

Comment: @Sedrick can you suggest me a way to this-> " I need to know is there a way to set values cell by cell through a loop or something"